# How to ignore rows with 0

Tags: r

Example data set:

```
tibble::tribble(
     ~Item,        ~Date, ~quantity,
     "saw", "01/01/2020",        0L,
     "saw", "02/01/2020",       10L,
     "saw", "03/01/2020",        5L,
     "saw", "04/01/2020",       20L,
     "saw", "05/01/2020",       30L,
     "saw", "06/01/2020",        0L,
     "saw", "07/01/2020",        0L,
  "hammer", "08/01/2020",       60L,
  "hammer", "09/01/2020",       70L,
  "hammer", "10/01/2020",       40L
  )
```

I want to subtract quantity in the min date from the max date for each material and so it ignores the dates that have 0

desired result:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Item, ~difference,
  "saw",        -20L,
  "hammer",       20L
  )
```

Comment: You indicate subtract the quantity in the min date *from* the (quantity in ?) the  max date.. Doesn't this make the value for `saw` equal to 30-10 = positive 20? (likewise, for `hammer`, I think should be negative 20?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the 0 values out, and then use `summarize()`, indexing on `min()` and `max()` of the `Date` value

```
df %>% 
  filter(quantity!=0) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  summarize(difference = quantity[Date==max(Date)] - quantity[Date==min(Date)])
```

Output:

```
  Item   difference
  <chr>       <int>
1 hammer        -20
2 saw            20
```